# Web to Contact form for a Website

Tags: web

Has anyone implemented Web-to-Contact just like Web-to-Lead? I want to build a VF page with "Enquiry form" with fields related to "Contact" object and embed this page in a website. Pls help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this

1)Build a simple visualforce page and expose via force.com sites. you can iframe force.com site inside your site

2)Build a public REST API and use that within your website

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

3)If you use wordpress there are standard plugins already available providing this functionality